# Export Parse.com class with Cloud Code

Tags: json, parse-platform, export, parse-cloud-code

How can I create a javascript function to put in Cloud Code of parse.com, which downloads the content of the class in a json file?
I've read through the Cloud Code Documentation at parse.com https://www.parse.com/docs/cloud_code_guide  but I haven't found any examples similar to what I need to do.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this for example (there a few ways). Remove // to limit the number of objects (2 or whatever). "english" being my class.
Then you need to read this function from your platform (mobile desktop etc) which you also need to know how to do. What platform do you use? I only know Corona SDK.

```
Parse.Cloud.define("getall", function(request, response) {
  var query = new Parse.Query("english");
  //query.limit(2)
  query.find({
  success: function(results) {
  response.success(results);
},
```